# How can I retrieve multiple documents in diferent positions within a mongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a colection in mongoDB that has the following scheme:

```
_id:61f0252bc1737b8ed50b5fa0
value:31.600000381469727
timestamp:2022-01-25T16:28:27.021+00:00
```

Let's assume I need to get every 10th item. I have tried using $set to add a new field that would contain the document index, as shown below:

```
"$set":{
    index: { $indexOfArray: [ "$$ROOT", "$$ROOT" ] }
}
```

to get something like this:

```
_id:61f0252bc1737b8ed50b5fa0
value:31.600000381469727
timestamp:2022-01-25T16:28:27.021+00:00
index: 1
```

and so on...

Then, I'd use a where clause like: **index % 10 == 0** to get every nth document.
The problem is that the **$set** aggregation is not working, I attempted looking for a solution in the mongoDB documentation, but I haven't realized a way to solve this.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can add your index field using: [`$setWindowFields`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using the MongoDB 4.2.12 version, and that method is not supported. Is there any other way? Thanks.